# Spring Batch not invoking ItemReader after Partitioner execution

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I would like configure SpringBatch using partitioner. Parttioner will partition a list of data into multiple chunks and ItemReader will process those data. But in my case after successfully invoking Parttioner it is not invoking ItemReader's read() method. Below are the code snippet and code. Could you please let me know whats wrong?

```
<batch:job id="cycleJob">
                        <batch:step id="step1">
                            <batch:partition partitioner="cyclePartitioner">
                                <batch:step>
                                    <batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="1">
                                        <batch:chunk processor="itemProcessor" reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="10">
                                        </batch:chunk>
                                    </batch:tasklet>
                                </batch:step>
                                <batch:handler task-executor="taskExecutor" grid-size="${maxThreads}" />
                            </batch:partition>
                        </batch:step>
                    </batch:job>

            <bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.navisys.besystem.batch.CycleItemProcessor">
                    <property name="transactionTemplate" ref="txTemplate"/>
                    <property name="processorType" value="Batch.executeCycle"/>
                </bean>
                <bean id="itemWriter" class="com.navisys.besystem.batch.CycleItemWriter" />

            <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
                    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="cycle-" />
                    <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="${maxThreads}" />
                </bean>
                <bean id="itemReader" scope="step" class="com.navisys.besystem.batch.CycleItemReader">
                    <property name="dao" ref="cycledao" />
                    <property name="cycleDate" value="${cycleDate}" />
                    <property name="batchIds" value="${batchIds}" />
                    <property name="switches" value="${switches}" />
                    <property name="workItemsPerMessage" value="${workItemsPerMessage}" />
                    <property name="policyMask" value="${policyMask}"></property>
                    <property name="mainFile" value="${mainFile}" />
                    <property name="datafileLocation" value="${datafileLocation}"></property>
                    <property name="data" value="#{stepExecutionContext['data']}" />
                </bean>

                <bean id="cyclePartitioner" class="com.navisys.besystem.batch.CyclePartitioner">
                    <property name="dao" ref="cycledao" />
                    <property name="cycleDate" value="${cycleDate}" />
                    <property name="batchIds" value="${batchIds}" />
                    <property name="currentSwitch" value="R"></property>
                </bean>


    public class CyclePartitioner implements Partitioner {
     @Override
        public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
            final Map<String, ExecutionContext> contextMap = new HashMap<>();
            List<BatchContractIdData> list = initialize();

            int partionCount = 0;
            int itemsPerList = (null == list || list.isEmpty())?1:(int)(Math.ceil(list.size()/gridSize));

            for(List<BatchContractIdData> data:Lists.partition(list, itemsPerList)){
                 ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
                 context.put("data", new ArrayList<BatchContractIdData>(data));
                 contextMap.put(getPartitionName(++partionCount), context);
            }

            return contextMap;
        }

    }
```

Comment: are you sure `CyclePartitioner.initialize()` returns a non-empty list?

Comment: I haven't override or implement initialize() method. Do I have to do this?

Comment: `Partitioner` is an interface and doesn't have a `initialize()` method. Who wrote it?

Comment: That's why. You mentioned to check CyclePartitioner.initialize() should return not empty list.